# Separate multi-channel audio equalization

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, equalizer

I am looking for a method to use audio equalization on my Linux PC to compensate for hearing loss.  Pulseaudio-equalizer seems to have the amplification variability and frequency bands needed.  My concern is that I need different equalization on the right and left channels; my hearing loss is not symmetric (I am using headphones).  Does Pulseaudio-equalizer have this capability (I cannot find it)?  Or, is there other software or methods that may achieve what I need?

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to equalize audio channels separately?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162863/is-there-a-way-to-equalize-audio-channels-separately)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was implemented in EasyEffects (formerly known as PulseEffects) as of version 4.4.2. See [this](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects/issues/353) GitHub issue for more details.

To install EasyEffects refer to the [README](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects#installation) for instructions for your OS. Ubuntu specific instructions can be found in their [wiki](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects/wiki/Package-Repositories#debian--ubuntu).

Comment: your recommendation was useful.  Stereo channels can indeed be adjusted independently with PulseEffects.  Select: Equalizer/Tools/Split Channels.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Ubuntu/Ubuntu Mate 22.04:

easyeffects seems not to be able to run properly due to PipeWire being used only for Ubuntu 22.10 and later.

You can install PulseEffects instead:

```
sudo apt install -y pulseeffects lsp-plugins
```