# Is there a way to equalize audio channels separately?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, equalizer

All the equalizers changes the frequency response of both right and left audio channel at the same time. All the headphones I own have uneven treble response (higher frequencies are produced at different loudness) and I want to eq them. Is there any software which will let me eq left and right channels separately?

Comment: Related: [Separate multi-channel audio equalization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071038/separate-multi-channel-audio-equalization)

Comment: You mean when you play a movie that has 5.1 channel sometimes gets louder in sound effects and then more silent in speech? Or I misunderstood maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was implemented in PulseEffects as of version 4.4.2. See [this](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects/issues/353) GitHub issue for more details.

To install PulseEffects refer to the [README](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects#installation) for instructions for your OS. Ubuntu specific instructions can be found in their [wiki](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects/wiki/Package-Repositories#debian--ubuntu).

Comment: PulseEffects can be installed like this: `sudo apt install -y pulseeffects lsp-plugins`